# Why onReceive() keeps getting called?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want my app to send a SMS when it receives a SMS, and I got it working. The problem is that once it gets 1 SMS it doesn't stop sending them.

Its like onReceive() method keeps getting called.

I would like it to send 1 SMS per 1 SMS received.

/******************************************************************************/

BroadcastReceiver class

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class SMSListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("031130130", null, "sms text", null, null);
    }
}
```

/*****************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************/

MainActivity

```
broadcastReceiver = new SMSListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED") && intent.getExtras() != null){
                    try{
                        doStuffsIfStolenOnce();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(Running.this,"Something went wrong:" + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, myFilter);
```

/****************************************************************************/

added intent filter and permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<receiver android:name=".SMSListener">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It feels like the problem is something obvious, but i can't find anybody else having this problem.

Comment: Why do you registering a receiver in Activity? You have declared it in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I didn't know i could reference it, thank You. I did find the source of my problem... didn't have a second phone so I was using my phone so send sms to my phone, so it kept on receiving -.- it and sending... . Sorry stupid mistake, should probably delete the question now

Comment: @Kosovir Although the problem was silly :) write your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem! Turns out it was my silly mistake, I was testing the app on my phone(real device) and i didn't have a second phone to send the "request" SMS. So I used my own phone to send the initial SMS and the app, working fine, send one back, but that meant it send a SMS to itself and once it received the second SMS it proceeded to send another one... and it got itself in a nice loop.